# Psycopg execute_values without id

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, execute

I try to insert a list of rows/tuple into my postgresql database. So I found the function execute_values() ... But it doesn't work that the rows get the id automaticly.

My code:

```
query = "INSERT INTO "+ self.table + " VALUES %s"
execute_values(self.cursor,query, row)
self.con.commit()
```

The first column in my database is the id and the first column of my row-tuple is TEXT (the second column in the database is also TEXT)

So I get the error:

```
psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation: invalid input syntax for type integer: "blub"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO whales VALUES ('blub...
```

So I guess it is because of the id.

Also I tried `template`, but the result isn't any better:

```
database.py", line 204, in insert_row
execute_values(self.cursor,query, row, "(%(name)s,%(is_member)s)")
File "C:\Just\a\Path\env\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\extras.py", line 1289, in execute_values
parts.append(cur.mogrify(template, args))
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Maybe I read the documentation wrong or don't understand templates...

Now the question:
How can I handle that? With "normal" executions I don't need to add an id. Is there a way to do so with execute_values()?
Or is the only way to get the ids first with a select and give unused ids to the execute_values also?

Comment: You should specify the columns, where the data belongs to: `INSERT INTO foo (text_col_1, text_col_2) VALUES ...`, assuming the `id` column auto increments.

Answer (score 2):

In Postgresql, for valid SQL, the list of values in an `INSERT` statement **must** correspond to the list
of column names specified. If no list of column names is specified, then the list of `N` values specified
must correspond to the **first** `N` columns in the table with the option of specifying `DEFAULT` to insert
the default value for those columns. With respect to a Postgresql `SERIAL` column such as that declared in the
following example table:

```
    CREATE TABLE test_insert_with_serial_column (
        id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        col1 VARCHAR,
        col2 VARCHAR
    );
```

The following SQL statements are valid:

```
    -- Specifying only the col1 and col2 columns, SERIAL id column will "auto-increment"
    INSERT INTO test_insert_with_serial_column(col1, col2) VALUES ('one_text', 'other_text');

    
    -- Specifying values for all columns with DEFAULT for the SERIAL id column
    INSERT INTO test_insert_with_serial_column VALUES (DEFAULT, 'one_text', 'other_text');
```

However, the following SQL is **invalid**:

```
    -- Failed to specify an integer value for the first SERIAL id column
    INSERT INTO test_insert_with_serial_column VALUES ('one_text', 'other_text');
```

This is because `one_text` will be associated with the `SERIAL` `id` column, and consequently,
an error message similar to the one seen by the OP results.

`psycopg2.extras.execute_values` is a helper function that can be used to insert multiple rows
of values (i.e., list of list of values) more efficiently. The input SQL query must contain
a single `%s` placeholder, which will be replaced by the `template` of placeholders. The default
`template` (i.e., if `None` is specified) is a simple positional sequence of placeholders
(i.e., `(%s, %s, ...)`) with the number of placeholders equaling the number of values to be inserted
for each row. Therefore, calling `execute_values` with:

```py
execute_values(cur, "INSERT INTO test_insert_with_serial_column VALUES %s",
               [('one_text', 'other_text')])
```

results in the same invalid SQL as above. Note that the above use of `execute_values` to insert only
one row instead of multiple rows is inconsequential to the error.

There are multiple solutions to this problem:

1. Specify the column names corresponding to the values in the input query

```py
execute_values(cur, "INSERT INTO test_insert_with_serial_column (col1, col2) VALUES %s",
               [('one_text', 'other_text')])
```

2. Provide a `template` that specifies a `DEFAULT` for the `id` column

```py
execute_values(cur, "INSERT INTO test_insert_with_serial_column VALUES %s",
               [('one_text', 'other_text')], template="(DEFAULT, %s, %s)")
```

3. Declare the `SERIAL` column as the last column in the table

```
    CREATE TABLE test_insert_with_serial_column (
        col1 VARCHAR,
        col2 VARCHAR,
        id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
    );
```

Then, calling:

```py
execute_values(cur, "INSERT INTO test_insert_with_serial_column VALUES %s",
               [('one_text', 'other_text')])
```

works. This last solution is a bit unconventional, but it takes advantage of the fact that if no list
of columns is specified, then the list of `N` values specified must correspond to the **first**
`N` columns in the table.

Comment: The problem that keeps me from using the first two solutions is the columns can be a variable amount. My prepared insert statement is meant to be used for multiple tables, with a varying number of columns. The only way I can see avoiding that issue is using your third solution.